# Examples of promise search problems that are easier than their non-promise variants?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, promise-problems

By promise search problem, I mean a search problem for which the solution is guaranteed to exist (e.g. find a solution to a linear system of equations, knowing that a solution does exist).

Are there any search problems for which adding this guarantee decreases the complexity of the problem, i.e. the algorithm is able to leverage the promise?

Comment: Given a bit string guaranteed to have a 1, a lookup table can be used to find the first 1.  That replaces testing each bit. logn (one memory reference) versus n (bit tests) speedup with the guarantee.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you can efficiently verify that any proposed solution is valid, no such problem exists.  There's a trivial reduction.  Suppose there was an algorithm $A$ that made use of the promise, and let its worst-case running time (on instances where the promise holds) be $T(n)$.

Now, for the search problem, you are given an instance where you're not sure whether the promise holds.  No problem.  Run $A$ on this instance, but terminate it after it executes $T(n)$ steps.  If $A$ outputs anything, verify that it is a valid solution; if so, output it, and if not, output that no solution exists.  If you have to terminate $A$, output that no solution exists.

This procedure gives an algorithm for the search problem that is always correct (the proof is by a simple case split on whether the instance has a solution or not), and whose running time is $O(T(n)+V(n))$, where $V(n)$ is the time to verify a proposed solution. Therefore you can solve the search problem about as fast as you can solve the promise search problem.

Answer (score 1):

The search problem “given a Turing machine that terminates, compute its output” is computable, but it is not computable without the promise (it is as hard as the halting problem).